Maximal interval of existence of a first order IVP
Suppose $y'(x) = f(y),\,x>0$ and $y(0) = 0$ is the given IVP. Given that $f$ is continuously differentiable on whole $\mathbb{R}$ and bounded as well.
Now by using Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ I can tell that the solution of this IVP will exist and be unique.
Further, the solution will be Lipschitz as well since the derivative is bounded as $f$ is bounded.
My question is about the interval of existence of the solution.
The answer given is that the solution will exist for all $x>0.$ How can we say that?

Since $f$ is bounded, say $|f(s)|\le M$ and therefore $|y'(x)|\le M$, you know that any local solution issued from $(0,0)$ will be contained in the sector $|y|\le Mx$. Therefore you can extend the solution indefinitely in the direction of the positive $x$-axis (it does not blow-up).
